# Placing the button on top right of UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have a UIImageView which is set to mode Aspect Fit. Now I want to place an edit button on top right corner of that image view. I am using auto layout and have a constraint of (Button->Trailing Space to superview) and the layout is connected via IBOutlet.

Once the image is set in UIImageView, I want to resize the ImageView Frame, so I can place the UIButton on top right. But UIImageView is not resizing as per image. Look at the gray part in the attached image (It is the background of ImageView)

```
imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
imageView.image = image;
[imageView sizeToFit];
buttonLeadingSpace.constant = imageView.frame.origin.x+imageView.frame.size.width-44;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should align your button with ImageView top & trailing. you can add constant=padding you need for your button.

UIImage is displaying as per your properties set for UIImageView (ie. contentMode = AspectFit). Here are the few options you might be interested in

1. If you want to fill the complete width just remove the height constraint from the UIImageView. It will fill the width and increase the UIImageView height as per image aspect ratio.
2. If you want same height and width of UIImageView set `contentMode = aspectFit`. this will fill the complete UIImageView but might clip the image.
3. Remove leading and trailing constraints from UIImageView. Align horizontal center and add image width constraint.